# Is there a way to insert multiple records into one2many field

Tags: python-3.7, odoo-12

I'm trying to create a history for some data, I need to copy one2many values into another one2many field.
The problem is im always getting only the last record

I have Tried to loop on each line of the one2many field

```
    def create_action(self):
        for agent in self:
            for line in agent.local_id:
                action_obj = self.env["historiq"]
                values = [(0, 0, {'localisation': value.localisation}) for value in line]
                historique = {
                'date_affectation': str(datetime.datetime.now()),
                'nom_agent': agent.agent_id.name,
                'post_occupee': agent.poste,
                'zone_affecte': values,}
                action_ids = action_obj.create(historique)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is There any way of taking related one2many field than you can take related field it will copy all record of one2many.

And can you show where you calling these function.

Comment: thats what i did , but it returns only one rec and the function is called using a button